# Jest not finding className

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am struggling to determine why my jest test can never find my components classes/
This is the component output from a debug statement

```
  <FileLine file={{...}} readOnly={false} onSelectedRevisionChanged={[Function: mockConstructor]}>
  <tr className="warning">
    <td className="col-xs-2">
      Data
    </td>
    <td className="col-xs-2">
      <select className="revision-selection form-control" value="1" onChange={[Function: value]}>
        <option value="1">
          1
        </option>
        <option value="2">
          2
        </option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td className="col-xs-2">
      Loading...
    </td>
```

My jest test is checking for the following

```js
it.only('sends selected revision when changed', () => {  
  const selectionCallBack = jest.fn();
  const component = mount(<FileLine file={fileUnderTest} readOnly={false} onSelectedRevisionChanged={selectionCallBack} />);

  //This will change the drop down to a different value
  const revisionSelection = component.find('revision-selection');
  console.log(component.debug());
  expect(revisionSelection.length).to.equal(1);

  revisionSelection.simulate('change', { target: { value: '2' } });

  expect(selectionCallBack).toBeCalledWith('packageRoot/F5___/Apps/GM/GM.E86_r2');
 });
```

The expect statement is always indicating that revisionSelection is always undefined. Pretty confused how that is possible given it is showing that class in the output.

Comment: You missed `.` in selector `component.find('revision-selection');`, should be `component.find('.revision-selection');`

Comment: I have tired that and still have the exact same result

Comment: What happens if you `console.log(component)`?  Do you see the `select` tag in the output?

Comment: @codenamev That returns ReactWrapper {}

Answer (score 0):

If `component.find('.revision-selection')` (note the leading `.` in the find) is returning `undefined`, then chances are good that the component isn't rendering.

I'd check that:

```
expect(component.find('.revision-selection')).to.have.lengthOf(1);
```

And then update your `revisionSelection` assignment to target the first match:

```
const revisionSelection = component.find('.revision-selection').first();
```